# PyDev: project not visible

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I was using PyDEV without issue but recently when I create a project in Eclipse the project is not visible in the PyDev perspective but is visible in the Java perspective. My project is a python project. It seems that the perspectives are a little mixed up.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 11):

My solution was:

1. Going to **PyDev Package Explorer**
2. Click **View Menu** button (arrow pointing down, top left area of the Package Explorer panel)
3. **Top Level Elements**
4. Click **Projects**

Comment: This might be a more robust solution compared to the one that requires `F10` key, which does not always function on every computer.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you added some filter which is hiding it in the PyDev package explorer?

I.e.: have you tried going to the PyDev package explorer filters (in PyDev package explorer > Ctrl+F10 > Customize View).

Or maybe you set the top-level to working sets and don't have a working set on PyDev? (i.e.: Ctrl+F10 > top level elements)

Or maybe you selected a working set which has nothing? (i.e.: Ctrl+F10 > select working set)

Comment: Have you tried removing unchecking all entries on the menu > customize view?

Comment: Also, what's checked on the menu > customize view > content?

Comment: I've given up and moved to LiClipse

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I've had to deal with this specific problem in Eclipse 4 Luna, and I have an idea for what's wrong.

**Use Package Explorer instead of PyDev Package Explorer.**

The native Package Explorer, when in working set view, appears to automatically create and populate the working set "Other Projects." PyDev's explorer does not appear to do this, at least not on my default Luna installation. As well, PyDev's assignment of projects to working sets appears broken on Eclipse 4 Luna, so users of PyDev Package Explorer may have trouble finding their projects between views.

**Enable Package Explorer:**
 - Window -> Show View -> Package Explorer

If **Package Explorer** not in menu:

1. Window -> Customize Perspective
2. Click the **Menu Visibility** tab.
3. Expand **Window**
4. Expand **Show View**
5. Find **Package Explorer** and put a check in it.
6. OK
7. Click **Window** then **Show View**, choose **Package Explorer** and rejoice.

I hope this helps at least one of you. I'm terribly new to Eclipse, and it is probably the single most unfriendly thing I've ever had to use. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Newly created projects did not show up. This is what brought me to this question. While looking at the answer provided by @alecor_Dev, which does not answer to the question, at least in my case, I managed to solve mine.

If you have a working set created and selected new projects will not show up. The easiest way to test is to go to:

```
PyDev Package Explore->View Menu  button (pointing down)-> Deselect Working Set.
```

If you has a working set but more projects in that workspace more projects will show up.

If you want to keep the view clean you can go back to your working set but add the new project by editing the working set:

```
PyDev Package Explore->View Menu  button (pointing down)-> Edit Active Woking Set.
```

And click on the project you want to add or remove.

I hope that this will help other with similar issues. While working set are a convenient way  to declutter the view, can add to confusion.

I Suggest to @Fabio Zadrozny to add some **visible** way of marking that we are working inside a working set.

I hope that @medPhys-pl can confirm this although he moved to LiClipse. Obviously, there can be other causes that can create this kind of behaviour, but the initial description of the problem seems very similar to mine and I hope that it will solve other people's issues.